# how to run 2 statements synchronously in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, synchronous

What I want to do is I need to add a key **rating** inside the listing object. In the following code, the rating key is not displaying on the console. I think it is because of the asynchronous call. What am I doing wrong?

```
    listing(){
         this.dataarray.push(response);
              this.dataarray.listing.forEach(element => {
                element['rating'] = element.qty;
              });
         this.loaddata();
    }
loaddata(){
console.log(this.dataarray);
}
```

Comment: Can you debug response in that method?

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous happening here. I am not sure how the issue can occur.  Can you share more details? What's `this.dataarray.listing`? Can you give a [mcve] that shows the incorrect behaviour

Comment: this.dataarray.listing ={ qty:1, df:3 , gn: 4}. Now I need to do this.dataarray.listing ={ qty:1, df:3 , gn: 4, rating:1}

Comment: @mansishrivastava then `this.dataarray.listing` is *not* an array - you cannot call `.forEach` on it. In fact, you should be getting an error on that line.

Comment: this.dataarray= [id:1,listing:[{ qty:1, df:3 , gn: 4, rating:1}]

Comment: this.dataarray= [id:1,listing:[{ qty:1, df:3 , gn: 4, rating:1}] is not correct json structure.
It should be something like below
this.dataarray= [
    {id:1, listing:[{ qty:1, df:3 , gn: 4, rating:1}],
    {id:2, listing:[{ qty:2, df:4 , gn: 5, rating:2}]
     ]

Comment: @VLAZ I got it.  Thanks

Comment: If you want to add new key in listing elements, please refer below code
this.dataarray.map(data => {
 data.listing = data.listing.map(listingData => ({…listingData, rating: listingData.qty}))
})

Answer (score -1):

If you have array data, and you want to add a key in each element of array, you can do as below

```
data = data.map(d => ({...d, rating: d.qty}));
```